# Assembly binding added in compiled output (app.config)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, assembly-binding-redirect

If I compile my application, an assembly binding is added automatically in the output. The specific assembly binding is not in the `app.config` in Visual Studio but in the created application config.

Is there any way, to check why the assembly binding is added automatically? The option `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` is not enabled.

I don't want to have the following assembly binding

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Pipelines" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.2" newVersion="4.0.2.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Furthermore, a completly differnt assembly version is installed.

**EDIT**

When looking into the compiler `binlog` result (compiled with msbuild /bl) this occurs:

[image]

This is pretty strange, because we've got the version `4.0.2.2` in the directory of `4.7.3`

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Actually**, **BindingRedirect** is the feature of the `packages.config` nuget management format and it still have a bit drawbacks.

> Is there any way, to check why the assembly binding is added
> automatically? The option AutoGenerateBindingRedirects is not enabled.

This behavior is controlled by the nuget package itself and the `packages.config` nuget management format. Since your code uses the part from different versions of the assembly and `packages.config` management format does not have the ability to switch them automatically.

So **BindingRedirect** comes up. And so far, some nuget packages have added this feature with `packages.config` and when you install this nuget package by `packages.config`, it will automatically add the **BindingRedirect** and it is not controlled by us.

**In order to** abandon the **BindingRedirect** and all these complex issues, I suggest you could use the new [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files). And it is a better one which has solved the **BindingRedirect** issue and optimized package management. And in this one, you do have to use **BindingRedirect**.

**Suggestion**

**1)** Right-click on the `packages.config` file--> click **Migrate packages.config to PackageReference**.

**2)** then delete any bindredirect on the `app.config` file.

**3)** delete any `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` in your `xxx.csproj` file if you have.

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, any `bin` and `obj` output folders.

[image]

**5)** restart your project and then build again to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We already use `PackageReference` in all projects. Furthermore, the problem also occurse when building in Azure DevOps (clean image for any build). But I will check all caches, and depending projects. Thank you so far!

Comment: Check every project and remove any `bindredirect` on every `app.config` or `web.config` and then delete bin and obj folder, check in every projects.